# IMAP IDLE method (ruby) always fires including archive / deletion events for Gmail servers

Tags: ruby, email, gmail, imap, message

I've specified resp.name == "EXIST" and for it to be an UntaggedResponse. I only want IDLE to fire when I receive new messages into my folder. According to the documentation, this should  work but for whatever reason, it's also firing whenever a message is archived or deleted.

```
@imap.examine 'INBOX'

# Add handler.
@imap.add_response_handler do |resp|
  if resp.kind_of?(Net::IMAP::UntaggedResponse) and resp.name == "EXISTS"
    # Always fires for archives and deletions...
  end
end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I experienced the same with imap.gmail.com. I used my script: https://gist.github.com/solyaris/b993283667f15effa579

Answer (score 0):

The `EXISTS` number will increase when new mail arrives and decrease when mail is moved to another mailbox, so you have to keep track of the number to disambiguate. Or you can look for `OK [UIDNEXT n]` instead, that should only be reported for new mail.